# Posting JSON as a request parameter not sending it raw

Tags: jmeter

I'm sending POST request on Jmeter with one of the parameters with json format. But JMeter is not sending it as a raw as you can see below. It's encoding the json and requesting with % and numbers... `**msg**` should be sending raw json.

I tried various options with encoding but none is working. How can I send json as a raw as a request parameter?

POST data:

```
trans_code=KycPartnerSender&version=1.0&pkg_id=1234123&timestamp=123123&**msg**=%7B%22sId%22%3A%7B%22weChatId%22%3A%22jnaS001%22%7D%2C%22sInfo%22%3A%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22jnaSender001%22%2C%22middleName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22QA%22%2C%22dob%22%3A%221958-01-31%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22001%40ZB.CA%22%2C%22taxId%22%3A%22467456789%22%2C%22mobilePhone%22%3A%224161231234%22%2C%22workPhone%22%3A%224161231234%22%2C%22citizenCountryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22residenceCountryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%7D%2C%22sAddress%22%3A%7B%22line1%22%3A%22123+Yonge+Street%22%2C%22line2%22%3A%22Suite+1902%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Toronto%22%2C%22countryRegionCode%22%3A%22ON%22%2C%22postalCode%22%3A%22M2M2M2%22%2C%22countryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%7D%2C%22sFundingSource%22%3A%7B%22accountNumber%22%3A%22123456789%22%2C%22accountHolderName%22%3A%22JNA+SENDER%22%2C%22routingNumber%22%3A%2200402652%22%7D%2C%22rId%22%3A%7B%22weChatId%22%3A%22jnaR001%22%7D%2C%22rInfo%22%3A%7B%22firstName%22%3A%22jnaReceiver%22%2C%22middleName%22%3A%22X%22%2C%22lastName%22%3A%22QA%22%2C%22dob%22%3A%221970-10-31%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22002%40ZB.CA%22%2C%22taxId%22%3A%22789456123%22%2C%22mobilePhone%22%3A%224161231234%22%2C%22workPhone%22%3A%224161231234%22%2C%22citizenCountryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22residenceCountryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22employmentStatus%22%3A%22Full+Time%22%2C%22occupationCode%22%3A%22102%22%2C%22industryCode%22%3A%22101%22%7D%2C%22rAddress%22%3A%7B%22line1%22%3A%22123+Bloor%22%2C%22line2%22%3A%22Suite+1900%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Toronto%22%2C%22countryRegionCode%22%3A%22ON%22%2C%22postalCode%22%3A%22M2M2M2%22%2C%22countryCode%22%3A%22CA%22%7D%2C%22rFundingSource%22%3A%7B%22accountNumber%22%3A%22987654321%22%2C%22accountHolderName%22%3A%22JNA+RECEIVER%22%2C%22routingNumber%22%3A%2200402652%22%7D%7D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Parameters table, select the Raw Body tab and just put your json body.

Of course it only works with Post method (not Get) so it should be ok for you.